# How to configure Moodle O365 SSO directly from the server?

Tags: moodle

Maybe some of you have faced a similar issue.. I am trying to automate Moodle deployment (including O365 SSO). I use auth_oidc plug downloaded from here https://moodle.org/plugins/auth_oidc . I registered an app in Azure: got client id and secret, and now I want to "add" these values to my moodle server. I know I can easily achieve by manually going to plugin settings in my Moodle site but I want to automate it and pass these values directly to a function which, from my understanding is located here /moodlesite.com/auth/oidc/settings.php (correct me if I am wrong). So any ideas how to achieve it??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look in `settings.php` there are 2 settings:

```
$settings->add(new admin_setting_configtext('auth_oidc/clientid', $configkey, $configdesc, '', PARAM_TEXT));

$settings->add(new admin_setting_configtext('auth_oidc/clientsecret', $configkey, $configdesc, '', PARAM_TEXT));
```

Those settings are saved in a table called `mdl_config_plugins`

So after installation you should be able to update them via SQL

```
UPDATE mdl_config_plugins
SET value = 'xxx'
WHERE plugin = 'auth_oidc'
AND name = 'clientid';

UPDATE mdl_config_plugins
SET value = 'xxx'
WHERE plugin = 'auth_oidc'
AND name = 'clientsecret';
```